# Interpreting results of windows memory diagnostics

Tags: windows, memory, diagnostic

I've been having some troubles with my computer lately, and tonight ran the windows memory diagnostic. I ran the extended test. It completed not showing any errors during the run, however I don't understand the results in the event viewer, they're somewhat inconclusive.

The test simply tells me that the windows memory test has completed. It doesn't say if it was successful or failed.

There's also some XML with some raw test data, but I can't tell what it means.

I'd post some more info, including screenshots however after the mem test it appears my computer is even more screwed up, I think I'm lucky to be able to type this in, but most of my windows are blacked out. The XML results are the best I can provide at the moment.

The system is an i7 870 (circa 2009) with 4GB 1333 MHz SDRAM3, an OCZ Vertex 120GB SSD, and currently and NVidia GT210. It was given to me a few weeks ago.

Originally the computer came with a Radeon HD 4890 but was blue screening with a video driver crash periodically. Thinking the card was kaput I swapped it out for the older NVidia which stopped the BSOD, but I still got the driver stopped responding and restarted errors with the screen going black.

Over the last few days there have been several BSODs on other than the graphic drivers, and twice on restart the system has tried to repair on restart but failed requiring me to use a restore point instead. In both cases, OS driver files were corrupt.

I thought this might be the SSD failing, but research indicated that memory is also possible so I ran the test last night.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks.

**Update**

I ran MemTest86 overnight, 19 passes, with no errors. So it looks like the memory is solid.

```
- System 
  - Provider 
     [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-MemoryDiagnostics-Results 
     [ Guid]  {5F92BC59-248F-4111-86A9-E393E12C6139} 

     EventID 2001 

     Version 0 

     Level 4 

     Task 0 

     Opcode 0 

     Keywords 0x4000000000000000 

     - TimeCreated 

     [ SystemTime]  2016-03-30T12:43:36.384959700Z 

   EventRecordID 2 

   Correlation 

   - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  4024 
   [ ThreadID]  4036 

     Channel Microsoft-Windows-MemoryDiagnostics-Results/Debug 

   Computer Beast 

  - Security 

  [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 


- UserData 

  - Results 

     MemDiagRawData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
```

Comment: What version of Windows?  How much system memory do you have? What problems have you been experiencing specifically?  Have you ran MemTestx86 instead?  There isn't anything helpful in that output by the way.

Comment: The 2001 mainly tells you that the memory test has run. if Everything Went fine you should have an Event with Event ID 1201. That said, do run Memtestx86 as Ramhound proposed, the built in memory diagnostic in Windows will only do a very basic memory testing and won't test your entire memory at that.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question with more info, please let me know if more needed. I'll download MemTest86 later and run that tonight.